# VS2013: Compiling Shaders with Shader Model 5.0

Tags: shaders, hlsl, visual-studio

When I try to compile two HLSL files included in my project, the compilation fails with an error:

> Error error X4502: invalid vs_2_0 input semantic 'INSTANCE'

However, I notice it's trying to use shader model 2.0; when I'm trying to use 5.0:

[image: Shader Model 5.0 Selected in Project Property Pages]

Why is the shader compiler trying to use the 2.0 model when I've told VS to use 5.0? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Make sure you right click -> properties on  each shader file and set the Shader Type as well. The property right above the shader model.

Comment: There could also be something else wrong, can you post your shader?

Comment: You should post your code. With DirectX 11 and Shader Model 5.0, you should be using ``SV_InstanceID``.

Comment: @JoeSwindell Thanks for your advice about setting the shader type, that was the problem. If you add an answer with the same comment I'll accept it.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn The instance semantic referenced here is per-instance data, not the per-instance ID.

Comment: For Direct3D 10.x era instancing, you don't use the legacy ``INSTANCE`` semantic. IF you want a user-defined semantic name, then you need to use a different string that isn't a known legacy semantic name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you right click -> properties on each shader file and set the Shader Type as well. The property right above the shader model in your graphic.

Answer (score -1):

you should set (/fx) in shader type